# Bash-Ubuntu 18.04-ROS-Melodic: Ping to IP address does not return anything

Tags: bash, ip, ping, ros, ifconfig

I have a `Velodyne Puck 16` sensor that I have been trying to connect to `ROS Melodic` for the past few days. My OS is `Ubuntu 18.04`. I was able to find out the address of the lidar using `WireShark`, as it is possible to see below:

[image: ip-address]

So the `IP is: 10.0.1.201`

After very very carefully following the installation procedure in the [official documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20Velodyne%20VLP16)  everything I was trying was unsuccessful.

So I decided to apply a simple `ping` procedure to the address of the lidar:

`ping 10.0.1.201` it does not return any package of information despite it seems connected.

The problem I have is that, despite I know the `IP` address of my `Velodyne 16` using `Wireshark`, the lidar does not answer to a simple test as the `ping` of the `id`.

## Steps I followed:

## 1 Configure your computer’s IP

Below the connection procedure: I created a `velodyne_interface` connection, see below:

[image: connection-status]

**Existing Connection**

[image: conn1]

**velodyne_interface**

[image: conn2]

## 2 Connecting your computer to LIDAR through terminal

```
emanuele@pc:~$ sudo ifconfig enp109s0 192.168.3.100
```

Add a static route to the LIDAR's IP address.

```
emanuele@pc:~$ sudo route add 10.0.1.201 enp109s0
```

## 3 Checking the configurations [Problem is here]

To check the connection open your web browser and access the following sensor’s network address.

**The problem** is that I never get to see the webpage showing the lidar data. Basically I never get to see the page below provided in the official documentation:

[image: velodyne]

What is happening? Why is that happening?

Comment: Do you have a route pointing to the sensor ? If not, then your ping goes to the global route, aka internet, where you can't find this address as it is a [local one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses)

Comment: @Zelnes, thanks for reading the question. My sensor is connected via ethernet to my laptop.

Comment: I updated the question adding the procedure and specifically pointing to the problem if that cold be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably some problems with the routing. You can try debugging the routing issues, some googling will probably help there. Some commands which might help pinpoint the problem `tracepath -n 10.0.1.201` and `ip route list`.

The easiest solution to your problem would be to just configure the "velodyne_interface" you created to the same subnet as your velodyne lidar. So in the "velodyne_interface" set your ip to 10.0.1.20 for example. Connect to the "velodyne_interface" connection, verify that you have the ip you set by typing `ip a` or `ifconfig` in some terminal and you should be able to access the Velodyne web interface from 10.0.1.201. From there you can configure the velodyne sensor networking to the settings you like.

Comment: thanks that solved the problem :) . That means that the [guideline](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20Velodyne%20VLP16) should actually be corrected as it is misleading and brings the user to erroneously put the wrong address from the beginning. Thank you so much for your help! :)